# in app purchase issue with status iOS

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

Can I test in app purchases while they are in status "Ready to Submit"
I am getting products from iTunes via code.

I have invoke this `SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:product];`

but I still don't have any callback in response (failed, restore, complete). Maybe it is connected to the status of in app purchase.

Comment: Did you add the payment to the queue? [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];

Comment: can you post more of your code?